# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.setProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Ob ject;)V

Tags: hibernate, jpa, heroku, playframework, jpa-2.0

I am getting this error while deploying my play 1.2.5 app on heroku.

```
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786454+00:00 app[web.1]: 21:47:45,786 ERROR ~
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786461+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786464+00:00 app[web.1]: @6ilc03hfb
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786466+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error (500) for req
uest GET /
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786468+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786469+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops: NoSuchMethodError
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786471+00:00 app[web.1]: An unexpected error occured caused
by exception NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.setProperty(Ljav
a/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786473+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786474+00:00 app[web.1]: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException
: Unexpected Error
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786476+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.Invoker$Invocation.onExc
eption(Invoker.java:244)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786477+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(I
nvoker.java:286)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786479+00:00 app[web.1]:    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!
)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786481+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodEr
ror: javax.persistence.EntityManager.setProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Ob
ject;)V
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786483+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.startTx
(JPAPlugin.java:375)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786484+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.beforeI
nvocation(JPAPlugin.java:345)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786486+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.plugins.PluginCollection
.beforeInvocation(PluginCollection.java:473)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786487+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.Invoker$Invocation.befor
e(Invoker.java:217)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786488+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(I
nvoker.java:277)
2014-06-30T21:47:45.786490+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 1 more
```

App is using postgres db with postgis extension. Can anyone please help me out to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make Neil Stockton's answer a little bit clearer:

1. API - set of JARs you program against. **This is in your development classpath.** Normally, APIs are Java Interfaces or abstract classes or delegates. If you are using Eclipse, this is the one in the Build Path. In Maven, this is the dependency you declare in your POM.
2. Implementation - set of JARs bundled in the server, or more specifically, the JPA container. These are implementations of the API you are calling in your code. These are NOT in your development classpath, **they are part of the server's classpath or libraries.** They are used by the JPA container (again, part of server installation) during runtime as the actual classes which the interfaces in your code are delegating execution onto.

Other technologies that use the API - Implementation compatibility are Servlet API - Web Container, EJB API - EJB Container.

As Neil mentioned, your CODE (dev classpath) uses JPA 2 but ONLY has JPA 1 on the server classpath.

TO SOLVE the issue, you need to consult the documentation of the server on how to download a version of the server that supports JPA 2.0. Some servers allow you to update the libraries so JPA 1 becomes updated to JPA 2.0.

If this is not possible (i.e. vendor server), then sadly YOU have to change your code to only use JPA 1 compatible API, which means you have to remove the call to EntityManager.setProperty and try to achieve it in some other means.

Answer (score 1):

As shown easily enough by looking at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) for JPA, there is a setProperty method in JPA 2.0. You therefore must be using a JPA 1 implementation yet have the JPA 2 API jar in the CLASSPATH, or you have a JPA 2 implementation and have the JPA 1 API jar in the CLASSPATH